# На картине было изображено существо с лапками(,) как у лягушки

Tags: пунктуация

Будьте добры, подскажите, нужна ли запятая: На картине было изображено существо с лапками(,) как у лягушки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***На картине было изображено существо с лАпками, как у лягУшки.***

Ударением здесь выделено сочетание ***существо с лАпками*** (предмет + несогласованное определение), а далее следует обособленный сравнительный оборот.

Сравнить: У этого существа лапки **как у лягУшки.** Оборот выделен ударением, а на существительное ударение не падает. Соответственно, пауза отсутствует

Таким образом, этот оборот в общем случае **может обособляться или не обособляться**, что зависит от расстановки логических ударений. Необособленный оборот тесно примыкает к существительному, занимая позицию  несогласованного определения.

1)  **При наличии согласованного определения** оборот обычно обособляется, тогда он занимает позицию второго (уточняющего) определения:

― Глаза как глаза, чуть зеленоватые, **как у лягушки**. [Виталий Губарев. Трое на острове (1950-1960)] Рот у него был огромный, **как у лягушки**, ― от уха до уха. [Юрий Герман. Дорогой мой человек (1961)]

2) В составе **другого обособленного оборота** может не обособляться (ударение падает только на сравнительный оборот, паузы нет):

Скосив большие глаза, **приподнятые как у лягУшки**, скат подпустил меня ближе, потом плавно взмахнул своими широкими треугольными крыльями, поднялся и поплыл прочь. [Ю. Курочкин. На подводных рифах Южной Австралии , 1968]

Также оборот не обособляется, если является **именной частью сказуемого**.

У сына кровь ***как у лягушки***…

И руки ― **как у лягушки**, бррр! [Георгий Владимов (1969)]. Тире здесь авторское, интонационное.